Update a table only if updated field is higher
I'm triying to upload some files with incremental data. The tabla has a PK (_id), but this _id could appears in many files with different values.
I'd like to load massively the files with a REPLACE INTO or similar, if the register doesn't exist then it must be inserted, but if the register already exists, it must check if the field
updated is later than the other one or not, and if it is, replace it, and if it is not, ignore.
Is this possible?
I have tried to do several tests with REPLACE and UPDATE or create a temporary table but without results

Use conditional code in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause.
INSERT INTO yourTable
SELECT * 
FROM tempTable
ORDER BY updated
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    col1 = IF(NEW.updated > updated, NEW.col1, col1),
    col2 = IF(NEW.updated > updated, NEW.col2, col2),
    -- repeat for all columns

If you're using pre-8.x MySQL, use VALUES(columnname) instead of NEW.columnname

Thanks. I assume that the conditional table should not have a PK in the sense that it should allow duplicate values, so that they can then be evaluated.

Do you mean tempTable._id? I assumed it would also be a PK, and it's unique in each file. You would load the file into the temp table, run this query, then empty the table and repeat with other files.

If it can be duplicated in tempTable, and there are multiple rows that satisfy NEW.updated > updated, it's unpredictable which one will be used.

Although you could use ORDER BY updated so it will always use the most recent one.

I had planned to load multiple files into the temp table at the same time; even if they had the same _id, and then run the query. Would that work?

Yes. As I said, add ORDER BY to produce predictable results.

I had planned to load multiple files into the temp table at the same time; even if they had the same _id, and then run the query. Would that work? This will work deterministically only when updated column (which is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, is it?) is unique over all your files data. If there are 2 rows in new data which have the same value in this column then the most last one will be applied. If there is no ORDER BY, then "the most last" matches the physical posession, if it is present and provides the uniqueness then according the ordering otherwise unpredictable.

@Akina True, although it only becomes a problem if the most recent updated timestamp is duplicated for an ID. Other duplicates will be overwritten by later timestamps.
